# Tensorflow data pipeline with from_generator is not producing data fast enough

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I am using tf.data.Dataset to build pipeline for training and I cannot seem to get the speed. I am using from_generator (see below) in pipeline and I am suspecting python global lock is part of the issue. I am struggling to figure out a design that can speed it up. I tried different variations of num_parallel_calls, cycle_length, block_length in the interleaves but none of them seem to help. Appreciate any insights.

**Tensorflow 2.0, Default Eager Mode.**

**Pipeline - Read TFRecords and feed data to training**

I have two generator functions that I am overlaying to spread the work load.

- generator_step1 - loads the tf_record file, uses map to parse data
- generator_step2 - processes the data and yields batches of data

**Pipeline Psuedo Code**

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(tf_records_files_list)

dataset = dataset.interleave(lambda x: tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(generator_step1, 
                                output_types=(tf.string, tf.float32), args=(x,batch_size,)),
                                cycle_length=2,
                                block_length=1)

dataset = dataset.interleave(lambda arg1, arg2: tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(generator_step2, 
                                output_types=(tf.float32, tf.int16), args=(arg1, arg2,)),
                                cycle_length=2,
                                block_length=1)

dataset = dataset.prefetch(5)
```

This runs on a powerful machine and I don't see I/O or CPU being the bottleneck. Any thoughts on how to improve or optimize this further? Appreciate any insights.

Comment: If you have enough RAM you can use `ds.cache` to load the data into the RAM or cache it to a file.

Comment: I have enough RAM but not nearly enough to cache all the data. I have 128GB RAM and the data is hundreds of GBs so that is not an option. I was hoping the pipeline can be designed with minimal lag but I am not able to get it to deliver consistent speed.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think you design is not optimal. First you create a `tf.dataset` and then you create another `tf.dataset` for each batch, which produces a lot of overhead. Instead of `interleave` I reccomend to use `.map`. Therefore, you have to rewrite the generators as a function that returns **one** sample at a time. Afterwards you shoudl do the batching by `tf.data`. Furthermore, you should use tensorflow functions (e.g. `tf.image.decode_iamge`) in you mapped functions.

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(tf_records_files_list)

dataset = dataset.map(load_func, num_parralel_calls=24)   

dataset = dataset.map(preprocess_func, num_parralel_calls=24)

dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size).prefetch(5)
```

This should do the job.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try this. In my mapped functions, I need to trim/process large arrays to create a batch. It is not image data but rather multi-dimensional discrete data. Once I move them to map, I will try to see if there are any  tf functions that I can leverage. Let me know if you have any pointers. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please described your data more in detail it give an example implementation. Furthermore, don't forget to mark the answer correct if helped you.

Comment: I tried to create a sample implementation but it became too complex. The trouble I am having is using map on function that can generate multiple batches. Our tfrecords have multiple samples in them so in our processing func, we create batches of data based on the training criteria. One TFRecord file can create multiple batches and we were using generators to do that. But with map, we cannot use generators. Any thoughts on how to look at it?

TFFile has multiple samples (each sample is 2048x100x500 )
load_fn loads the TFRecord files
process_fn - basic ops on arrays, create multiple batches